# python - newbie problem with for loop and conditionals

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm having problems with for and conditionals in my code.

I' trying to do a search inside a .csv and working with pandaspd. I have something similar to this

```
for i in csv_row:
    if csv_row == 'hello':
       print('FOUND')
```

So what I'm trying is to find in an specific row the word "hello" and then to print FOUND. But it doesn't work. But if I change the == to != it will print FOUND for each row in the .csv file.

What can I do? I couldn't find help searching online.

Thanks!

Comment: Seems like `csv_row` has a newline at the end or something. If you read in a file with `readlines()` that would be the case. You should print out `csv_row` and see what its contents are, and its length. You could also loop through each character in it and print its `ord()` and see if there's anything weird there.

Comment: Try `csv_row.startswith('hello')`  or `'hello' in csv_row`.

Comment: Usually we expect the [mre] to have a minimal example of the data you are operating on. What is `csv_row`?

Comment: This code looks wrong.  Why are you bothering to loop over each element in the row with `for i in csv_row`, if you're not actually checking `i`?

Comment: changing `==` to `!=` will print FOUND because `!=` is the opposite of `==`. When `==` evaluates to False, we would expect `!=` to evaluate true (and vice-versa)

Comment: @wwii imagine that csv_row is a row in a csv file that looks something like:

`hello
hi
hi
hi
hello
`

And I want to iterate in it and found the "hello". I also tried cheking "i" as @JohnGordon said but the results are the same

Comment: We need to see the full code and the contents of the csv file.  Otherwise we're just guessing at the cause.

Comment: [How to debug small programs.](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)
|
[What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](//stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/843953)

Comment: Also, one of the keywords in [mre] is **reproducible**. We aren't clairvoyant, so we can't tell you how to fix your issue if you don't provide code that we can run _as-is_ and supporting files to reproduce your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to refer `i` instead of csv_row.

```
for i in csv_row:
    if i == 'hello':
       print('FOUND')
```

if csv_row is a text file or whatever.

```
f= open("csv_row.csv", "r")

for i in f.readlines():
    if 'hello' in i:
       print('FOUND')

f.close()
```

edit:
As you are using pandas, you can do something like this.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('csv_row.csv')

# get each row data as a list
for row in df.iterrows():
    # iterate through list and find pecific value  
    for i in row:
         if 'hello' in str(i):
             print('found', i)
```

You can edit the code as you want.

Comment: I tried this but now if I use != it also wont work

Comment: what you get when you run this with == and !=  .

Comment: I get nothing. So I don't know what else I could do

Comment: May be you have forgotton to add the file extension. Also try `in` instead of `==`, because it checks the compares the whole line. Edited the answer, check if that works.

Answer (score 0):

!= means not equal, that's why you get "FOUND" every time.

You could do this:

```
import csv
with open(r'path/samplecsv.csv') as file_obj:
    reader_obj = csv.reader(file_obj)
    for row in reader_obj:
        if row == "hello":
           print("FOUND")
```